# Was Knight Rider inspired by Batman?

Tags: knight-rider

Let's compare Knight Rider and Batman.

- Batman wore a mask. So did Michael Knight because he had a face transplant that changed him from Michael Long
- Devon in Knight Rider = Alfred in Batman
- Knight Corp in Knight Rider = Wayne Corp in Batman
- Knight Corp truck = Bat Cave in Batman
- Both Batman and Michael Knight have no super powers
- Both Batman and Michael cannot fly; but both can glide or raise themselves with technology; Batman uses his cape; Michael uses his car KITT.
- Both have a high tech car
- Both Batman and Michael fight crime as loners outside of the legal cliques
- Batman has Robin as his sidekick; Michael has KITT

The only difference to me is the lack of a Joker in Knight Rider; there was no consistent villain, only short term ones in Knight Rider such as Goliath or Karr.

So my question: did the creators of Knight Rider use Batman as a template?

Comment: I really think you are reaching here,

Comment: I don't; I could have added more. Michael's black car has the same effect as Batman's black cape. Both suggest secrecy and darkness.

Comment: I think you can make the same associations with plenty of other shows since you're describing a recipe.

Comment: I disagree; my list is long and specific.

Comment: All of which are a stretch.

Comment: Heroes have a way to hide their identity, they have (usually) helpers, a way to fund their adventures and a way to find out who to fight, a place to hide/think, they have powers (in this case, lack there of. They use tech), they have a way of transportation (vehicle or flying), they have a persona and MO (fight alone), they usually have side kicks or someone they interact with for story / character development. This is essentially the recipe/template taken from your list, now apply that to say Air Wolf or some other show.

Comment: When did Michael Knight wear a mask? was it some specific episode? Definitely not during the whole series.

Comment: I disagree. I have applied it with specific intent. For instance the inside of the Knight Corp truck is a lot like the bat cave. High tech. Secretive. Often has Devon in it who is like Alfred.

Comment: to answer your question, "did they use Batman as a template?" - They used a template just as I outlined in my above comment.

Comment: Why Batman if Booster Gold suits better? Or even Blue Bettle?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## No.

...but there *was* another completely separate inspiration.

Glen Larson said...

> "I wanted to do **The Lone Ranger** with a car," Larson said of the show. He went even further by saying, "If you think about him riding across the Plains and going from one town to another to help law and order, then K.I.T.T. becomes Tonto.”
>
> <sup>[Source](http://mentalfloss.com/article/502245/10-fast-facts-about-knight-rider)</sup>

Comment: So basically all are based an a set of tropes probably going back even further than The Lone Ranger.